# Linux distrib with apache and mysql pre installed

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, distributions

Is there a Linux distro with apache and mysql pre installed?

I just want a light and fast installation of apache + mysql + ftp server + phpmyadmin

Comment: Can't think of any where they aren't available; all can be configured for "automated install" with customized package lists.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if such a distro exists, maybe having a look at XAMPP would be worthwile for you. -> http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

"XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP and Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to install and to use - just download, extract and start."
It is available for Windows, Linux, MacOS X and Solaris.
Using this you would just have to install an FTP server and PHPMyAdmin manually afterwards.

BTW if you google for example 'Linux AND LAMP', which stands for Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP, you will find installation instructions for almost every linux distribution.
You could just take the one that seems the easiest, make a quick basic install of the distribution and follow up with a simple tutorial as well.